# Exporting pre-processor macros from a framework module

Tags: objective-c, xcode, module, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a framework that I ship as part of my app. It has an umbrella header and normally I just do #import Foo/Foo.h and everything is great.

I thought I'd try importing it with the @import Foo; syntax, and while the app still compiles and runs fine, Xcode no longer auto-completes any of the #defines in the headers, which makes it quite annoying to work against.

Is this just a thing I have to deal with, or is there a way to export defines/macros?

Comment: Wondering this too, as when using modules MAX() no longer evaluates to the double evaluation-safe version from NSObjcRuntime.h.